# Agregar datos a un objeto indexado en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, json, javascript-objeto

Requiero guardar datos en un objeto indexado `Javascript`, el cual contenga datos del usuario y unos datos adicionales que se vayan agregando al objeto, es decir lo siguiente:

```
{"datos":{
  "nombre":"carlos"
},
  "adicional":[
    {
      "codigo":"1",
      "comentario":"hola"
    },
    {
      "codigo":"2",
      "comentario":"adios"
    }
  ]
}
```

El problema es en el apartado de **adicional** que solo se guarda un registro, aca les muestro el código:

```js
var respuestas = {};
respuestas['datos']=null;
respuestas['adicional']=null;
function Datos() {
    var nuevo = {
        nombre: $('#nombre').val()
    };
    respuestas['datos'] = nuevo;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(respuestas));
}
function Otros() {
    var nuevo = {
        codigo: $('#codigo').val(),
        comentario: $('#comentario').val()
    };
    respuestas['adicional']=nuevo;
    //respuestas['adicional'].push(nuevo);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(respuestas));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<b>Datos</b>
<input type="text" placeholder="nombre" id="nombre" onkeyup="Datos();">
</div>
<div>
<b>Adicional</b>
<input type="text" placeholder="codigo" id="codigo">
<input type="text" placeholder="comentario" id="comentario">
<input type="button" value="Agregar" onclick="Otros()">
</div>
```

Entonces la idea es que, cuando escribo en el campo de **nombre** se vayan actualizando los `datos` en el objeto, lo cual funciona todo bien, sin embargo cuando **agrego** un parametro adicional solo se guarda un registro y cada vez que inserto uno nuevo se sobreescribe el anterior.
Claramente el error esta aqui:

```
respuestas['adicional']=nuevo;
```

Entonces ¿Cómo agrego datos solamente en el item de adicional? pensé que seria parecido a un array `respuestas['adicional'].push(nuevo);` pero muestra error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casi lo tienes. Entiendo que tu idea es pushear en un arreglo los elementos que se van a ir generando en el objeto `adicional`:

```
respuestas['adicional'].push(nuevo);
```

Sin embargo, esto no ocurre debido a como lo inicializas arriba:

```
respuestas['adicional']=null;
```

Aquí, el objeto `adicional` estaba siendo definido como un objeto nulo en lugar de un array vacío. Tendrías que inicializarlo como un array vacío para indicar que se van a almacenar los elementos ahí dentro, así:

```
respuestas['adicional']=[];
```

Código completo:

```js
var respuestas = {};
respuestas['datos']=null;
respuestas['adicional']=[];
function Datos() {
  var nuevo = {
    nombre: $('#nombre').val()
  };
  respuestas['datos'] = nuevo;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(respuestas));
}
function Otros() {
  var nuevo = {
    codigo: $('#codigo').val(),
    comentario: $('#comentario').val()
  };
  // respuestas['adicional']=nuevo; // esto ya no lo necesitamos
  respuestas['adicional'].push(nuevo);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(respuestas));
}
```

```html
<div>
  <b>Datos</b>
  <input type="text" placeholder="nombre" id="nombre" onkeyup="Datos();">
</div>
<div>
  <b>Adicional</b>
  <input type="text" placeholder="codigo" id="codigo">
  <input type="text" placeholder="comentario" id="comentario">
  <input type="button" value="Agregar" onclick="Otros()">
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Suponía que era algo tan simple, muchas gracias.